# How to make recapitulation data group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Anybody know how to make a recapitulation data with group by date?. i want to collect all transaction in 1 day/week/month. i want to joining table `Transaction` and `Detail Transaction`, which is have column that will show in recapitulation. I'm stuck on this query. any reply would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT a.TransactionID,
       a.Buyer_Code,
       a.Date_Transaction,
       b.NuggetID,
       b.Qty,
       b.Sub_Total,
       a.Total_Price
FROM   Transactions a,
       DetailTransaction b
GROUP  BY a.Date_Transaction
```

Comment: What is **recap data** ? If possible add sample data and expected result

Comment: ohh i'm sorry, i mean recapitulation, edited

Comment: You will need to add more data along with expected result and actual result..look here to know,how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i getting this error message `Column 'Transactions.TransactionID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @AdityaRizky - If you want help then you need to show sample data and expected result. Don't makes us to guess your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Might be what you are looking for.

```
SELECT a.TransactionID,
       a.Buyer_Code,
       a.Date_Transaction,
       b.NuggetID,
       QTY = SUM(b.Qty),
       SubTotal = SUM(b.Sub_Total),
       TotalPrice = SUM(a.Total_Price)
FROM   Transactions a
JOIN   DetailTransaction b On your keys
GROUP  BY a.TransactionID,
       a.Buyer_Code,
       a.Date_Transaction,
       b.NuggetID,
```